# How to prove using the definition that matrix $A$ is negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-forms

I'm trying to prove that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    -2 & 2\\
    2 & -5\\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

is negative definite. I can do it using the principal minors, but I am trying to understand how to do it using only the definition of a negative definite matrix, i.e., using the quadratic form associated with it.

Comment: Can you represent the form as the negative of a sum of squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition.** A real symmetric matrix $A$ is called *positive definite* if $x^\intercal A x > 0$ for every real nonzero vector $x$ of compatible size.

**Definition.** A matrix $A$ is called *negative definite* if the matrix $-A$ is positive definite.

In your case,
$$
x^\intercal (-A) x = \cdots = 2(x_1 - x_2)^2 + 3x_2^2,
$$
as desired. You should work through the missing steps to verify the above.

*Remark.* Your matrix $-A$ happens to be a [weakly chained diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_chained_diagonally_dominant_matrix) [L-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-matrix).
By a [well-known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_chained_diagonally_dominant_matrix#Relationship_with_nonsingular_M-matrices), this means that it is an [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix). A symmetric M-matrix is also called a [Stieltjes matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_matrix). Stieltjes matrices are positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

> > **Lemma** $:$ A matrix $A$ is negative definite $\implies$ all the eigen values of $A$ are strictly negative.
> >
> > **Proof** $:$ Let $\lambda$ be an eigen value of $A$ corresponding to the eigen vector $X (\neq 0).$ Then by the given hypothesis $$\begin{align} X^t A X  & < 0. \\ \implies \lambda X^t X & < 0. \\ \implies \lambda & < 0. \end{align}$$ (since $X^t X > 0$ for $X \neq 0$).

In your case the eigen values of the given matrix $A$ are $-1$ and $-6$. So both the eigen values of the given matrix $A$ are negative. Hence by the above lemma the given matrix $A$ is negative definite.